# VBA Outlook Getting the "Reply-To" Email Address from the Email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to put together a script that will send a template based email back to Reply-To email addresses using Outlook Rules. I found using Item.ReplyRecipients(1) works great on certain emails where the email address is stored directly in the reply-to field.

Such as when the header has:

Reply-To: EmailAddress@gmail.com

However, other emails have the header come through like below. In this case Item.ReplyRecipients(1) only will return Bob Smith and not the actual email stored in the < >.

Reply-To: "Bob Smith" < EmailAddress@gmail.com >

I'm at a loss as to how to grab the actual email address in that circumstance. The full script is below

```
Sub BillAutoReplywithTemplate(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oRespond As Outlook.MailItem



Set oRespond = 
Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Outlook 
Templates\TemplateTest.oft")

With oRespond

   .Recipients.Add Item.ReplyRecipients(1)
   .Subject = "Re: " & Item.Subject
   .HTMLBody = oRespond.HTMLBody & _
           vbCrLf & "---Original Message Below---" & vbCrLf & _
           Item.HTMLBody

.Send
End With
Set oRespond = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: is `Reply-To: "Bob Smith" < EmailAddress@gmail.com >` on email body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReplyRecipients(1) will return an instance of the Recipient object, which you pass to Recipients.Add, which expects a string. So VBA converts the object to string by reading the default property (Name). Change the line

```
.Recipients.Add Item.ReplyRecipients(1)
```

to

```
if Item.ReplyRecipients.Count > 0 Then
  .Recipients.Add Item.ReplyRecipients(1).Address
End If
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I knew there had to be something like that, but couldn't find any info in their documentation after like a days worth of looking. Probably just don't know the terms to search for. New to the whole VBA and coding in general. Appreciate it a ton!